# Is that possible to check was onCreate called because of orientation change?

Tags: android

I need to act differently in `onStart()` method depending on how `onCreate()` was called in result 
of `orientation change` or not. Is that possible to check it?

Actually what I need is to do `something` when activity  **starts except a case when user changes orientation**.

I need to clearly distinguish cases when user just switched to another application and returned back OR he changed device's orientation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    boolean fromOrientation=false;
    SharedPreferences myPrefLogin;
    Editor prefsEditor;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prefsEditor = myPrefLogin.edit();
        myPrefLogin = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        fromOrientation = myPrefLogin.getString("fromOrient", false);

        if(fromOrientation) {
             // do as per need--- logic of orientation changed.
        } else {
             // do as per need--- logic of default onCreate().
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        prefsEditor.putString("fromOrient", true);
        prefsEditor.commit();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(fromOrientation) {
            prefsEditor.putString("fromOrient", false);
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }  
}
```

flag **fromOrientation**(tells the state either configuration had been change or not)
above we had done like by defalut we are considering that `onCreate()` is not called from by changing orientation. If orientation changed(`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`) then we set the flag value in preference which let us know whether `onCreate()` is called from on orientation or not.
And finally `onDestroy()` we again reset the orientation flag.

Comment: This is not going to work anymore. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html instead.

Answer (score 14):

Following Nahtan's idea I wrote this:

in onCreate():

```
if ( (oldConfigInt & ActivityInfo.CONFIG_ORIENTATION)==ActivityInfo.CONFIG_ORIENTATION ) {
    // ... was rotated
} else {
    // ... was not rotated
}
```

in onDestroy():

```
super.onDestroy();
oldConfigInt = getChangingConfigurations();
```

Answer (score 5):

Just check the bundle: when the activity is first started the bundle will be null. If there is an orientation change, it should be non-null.

From the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null.

**Edit:** I don't *think* you have to supply a bundle in onSaveInstanceState for it to be non-null after an orientation change, but that would be trivial.

Comment: Actually what I need is to do `something` when activity starts except a case when user changes orientation (copied from description)

Comment: Then just check if the bundle is null in onCreate, and if so, do the "something".

Comment: Gotcha; misunderstood that you just wanted to identify the first call. In that case I think I have a better answer I'll post seperately.

Comment: Works for me when I have a Timer in an activity that I want to start once, and the activity is finished before being started again.

Answer (score 5):

Try [getChangingConfigurations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getChangingConfigurations%28%29). Use this to discover when the activity is being destroyed because of an orientation change, set a flag, and check that flag when onCreate is called.

This has the advantage of letting you know why the activity is restarting without overriding orientation configuration in the manifest.

Comment: As per the reference document, this method is not 100% reliable though, and is recommended to be used only as a hint

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, save the state:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            // app started afresh, don't check orientation
            /* do application first-run stuff */
        } else {
            // re-started, so check for orientation change
            boolean orientationChanged = false;
            if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                int lastOrientation = savedInstanceState.getInt("last_orientation");
                orientationChanged = (getOrientation() != lastOrientation);
            }

            if(orientationChanged) {
                // orientation changed
                /* do stuff */
            } else {
                // orientation has not changed
                /* do stuff */
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("last_orientation", getOrientation());
    }

    private int getOrientation() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not work if you minimize the application being in portrait mode and start it again from landscape mode. In this case you would have different orientations and you trigger your if condition, which should not happen by requirement.

Comment: Why do you need to determine if the user has changed orientation inside or outside of your Activity?

Comment: Because I need to one one thing when user launches the application, but not when he uses it (like change orientation of his device).

Comment: The simplest way to check if the user has launched the game afresh is to check if `savedInstanceState` is null (as suggested by Nathan), which you can add to the above code. I think you're getting bogged down by the concept of apps being 'open' or 'closed' (ala a PC), when really, in Android, you shouldn't be differentiating between the two states.

Comment: Actually, Nathan's answer is definitely worth chasing up!

Comment: You should differentiate because if you work in portrait mode your currentOrientation == 1 (for example), then you switch to another app, change orientation to landscape and switch back to the app. Your currentOrienataion == 0. In this case you have oldOrientation != currentOrientation -> orientation changed and the `thing` I need to do when user start the app doesn't happen. I hope I'm clear this time.

Comment: See amended code. Is that closer to what you want? If the app has been started up afresh, the orientation is not checked at all. Otherwise, it's checked to see if it's changed.

Comment: there would be a case when user worked with app, then switched to another, changed orientation then back to the app and it triggers the case orientations are different and code executed. This is one special case which make this hard to do because you never know was the application restarted because of user's switching to another app and then returning to it OR it was restarted because of orientation change. That's the problem. Sorry for making it so unclear all this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.
On each onStart, you can save the current orientation (take a look [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-size-and-orientation-of-the-screen)).
If it is the first onStart call, do nothing, on other calls, check if the orientation has changed and do what you need.

```
private int m_currentOrientation = -1;

public void onStart()
{
   int oldOrientation = m_currentOrientation; // 
   m_currentOrientation = getCurrentOrientation(); // As in the link above
   if ((oldOrientation != -1) && (oldOrientation != m_currentOrientation))
   {
       // Do what you need
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `m_currentOreintation` is always `-1` because on each orientation change new instance of your class activity instantiated.

Comment: You can use the onSaveInstanceState, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state/151940#151940

Comment: Anyway `onCreate()` can happen not only after orientation change, but in some other cases also (for instance, being in app go to home screen and back)

Comment: But in that case, the m_CurrentOrientation will be the same.

Comment: @Lior Ohana, the value of the oldOrientation will always be the same, because when there is config changes the whole activity restarts itself, thus oldOrientation remains the same.

Comment: @Nikola, that's not completely true because you can save the value in saveInstanceState(). This approach just doesn't work when you just start the app second time, when there were no conf changes.

Comment: @AndroidNoob, You wrote that it can happen "not only after orientation change", I know, but that's OK because the value of the m_currentOrientation will be the same when the change was not orientation. No?

Comment: @Lior, what you proposed is correct, but I've updated a description a little bit, the case became a little bit harder. Your suggestion doesn't work if you just start the application second time, the value would be -1 and two values are equal, this won't trigger the case, but it should. I need some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, why don't you handle configuration chanages (orientation) by yourself. Tell android not to handle screen orientation.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Then you just override onConfigurationChanged method to get your rearranging of view or whatsoever things need to be done. Leave things that you don't wanna get executed.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  //do your jobs 
}
```

Comment: This will cause problems down the road if he wishes to have different layouts for portrait and landscape modes. Android restarts activities during orientation changes for a reason.

Comment: It is still possible to set different layouts by this method. All we need to do is to check Orientation from new config. Put inside a condition statement. Do "setContentView(properlayout)". 

Anyway, I do agree with the fact that " Android restarts activities during orientation changes for a reason". But it is down to us to do  what we want to achieve. Is it?

Comment: If you handle rotation this way and call `setContentView` from `onConfigurationChanged`, state of your views is not saved and restored. If you have `EditView` for example, it's content will be reseted.

Answer (score 0):

The `mCurrentOrientation` will be -1  if the app is starting for the first time.

```
static int mCurrentOrientation = -1;

public void onStart()
{
   int oldOrientation = mCurrentOrientation; 
   mCurrentOrientation = getCurrentOrientation(); 
   if ((oldOrientation != -1) && (oldOrientation != mCurrentOrientation)) {
       // Do your something here.
   }
}
```

If I understood your question correctly, I think this should work for you.