# Run the application in Landscape mode only?

Tags: android, landscape

I want to run a Hello World sample application only in landscape mode on my Device.

If the device changed to portrait, I would then like to raise one toaster. For example "please change to landscape mode to run your application".

How should I do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can go for both programmatically as follows:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or also in manifest file you can give here as

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"  android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

add this to your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

It will fix your orientation to landscape mode and you need not to show any toast to user.

Answer (score 3):

in your Manifestfile(xml)

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
```

refer this also [Is that possible to check was onCreate called because of orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295804/is-that-possible-to-check-was-oncreate-called-because-of-orientation-change/7397085#7397085)

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

Log.v("log_tag", "display width is "+ width);
Log.v("log_tag", "display height is "+ height);

if(width<height){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device is in portrait mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device is in landscape  mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges)-attribute for the Activity you want to catch the screen-orientation change for.

After that, the [`onConfigurationChanged()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) in your Activity will be called when the orientation changes.

To check which orientation is currently displayed, check this older post: [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

After that, you can show off your message or do whatever you like (of course you can also set it to only show in landscape).